# Titles in MS word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word

I used to work with MS 2007 all the time and it had some titles like:

Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3, Heading 4, Title, I dont have these in MS Word 2013, How can I bring them back?

[image: This is what I see]

Above is what I see.

[image]

This is what I want to see...

Comment: Ah, I see, have you changed the default page theme?

Comment: @BigChris I don't know actually, I copy paste stuff from one document to another ...

Comment: See my amended answer

Comment: Does it only happen when you have that one specific document open? If so, then it's something about that document's formatting, not a problem with Word.

Comment: @techie007 I guess 2013 doesn't have 2007 styles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Word 2013 ribbon under "DESIGN" you have some design style examples. There is a down arrow and below it another down arrow with a line above it. Click the lower of the two. is there an option to "Reset to Default Style Set"... what does that do if you try it. i don't have Office 2013 installed so I'm unsure...

[image]

Comment: I know where they are, I updated my question have a look please.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply any "missing" styles to text by typing its name in the *Apply Styles* pane (Ctrl+Shift+S).

In that same dialog box, you can click the *Modify* button and verify that "Add to the Styles gallery" is selected; Word (re-)adds the style to the gallery on the Home tab.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-word/word-2013-heading-1-and-2-missing-in-styles/7a12854a-49c1-4246-a159-76866730552a)